# Trying to install Xdebug with PHP 8.0 - The Zend Engine API version 420200930 which is installed, is newer

Tags: php, xdebug, php-8

I've recently installed PHP 8.0 on my Ubuntu 20.04 server and I'm trying to get Xdebug working with it. I've installed it as per the directions from https://xdebug.org/wizard:

```
Installation Wizard
Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 8.0.0
Zend API nr: 420200930
PHP API nr: 20200930
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
OPcache Loaded: yes
Configuration File Path: /etc/php/8.0/cli
Configuration File: /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php/20200930

Instructions

Download xdebug-3.0.2.tgz
Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.
On your Ubuntu system, install them with: apt-get install php-dev autoconf automake
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-3.0.2.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-3.0.2

Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20200930
Zend Extension Api No:   420200930

If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.
Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20200930
Edit /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so
Make sure that zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so is below the line for OPcache.
Please also update php.ini files in adjacent directories, as your system seems to be configured with a separate php.ini file for the web server and command line.
```

But I get this error when doing `php -v`:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320190902.
The Zend Engine API version 420200930 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.
```

When I ran phpize, I got this output:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
```

So I'm not sure what I need to do here. Why am I unable to use the right Zend API version?

Ubuntu reports that I have the lastest versions of `autoconf`, `automake` and `php-dev`

Comment: Maybe something in your `php.ini` is looking at an old copy of XDebug built for PHP 7 in a different location?

Comment: Need a debugger for the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue. After some investigation I realized the problem was caused because the configuration path assumed during the compiling process was pointing to the global php-config (another php version). So I just had to run the compilation with the flag (Xampp in my case):

```
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

The next steps were the same you did and it works like a charm.